# Why does Jest coverage report break when changing the testMatch regex?

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, jestjs, babel-jest

With the following configuration the coverage reports breaks when changing the `testMatch` cli option. I have tried setting the `collectCoverageFrom './src/*.js'` option but this hasn't fixed the issue either.

**./src/sum.js**

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

**./test/sum.js**

```
const sum = require('../src/sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
},

"scripts": {
    "test": "jest ./test/*.js --testMatch '**/*.js' --coverage --coverageDirectory './test-coverage'"
}
```

**Output** from `npm run test`

```
 PASS  test/sum.js
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.125s
Ran all test suites matching /.\/test\/sum.js/i.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `testRegex` parameter:

```
jest --testRegex='./test/.*\.js$' --coverage --coverageDirectory './test-coverage'
```

Now the output looks like this:

```
PASS  test/sum.js
✓ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (3ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 sum.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.769s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job.